# get and display user location postcode in edittext on location button click like in just eat app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do something like the picture below of just eat app using android studio. I am yet to start building my app but I would like to know how to implement getting user postcode and showing it in the edittext field. Any help will do.

![img1] https://drive.google.com/file/d/186D7fjSvJOhEQdep_fU4dnkUGV-Yi8Ya/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to allow users to identify their post code from their address you might find the Post Office Adress File (PAF) useful although this is a paid for service.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcode_Address_File
https://www.royalmail.com/business/services/marketing/data-optimisation/paf

Some developers may be able to get free sample data for developing their application

https://www.poweredbypaf.com/access-to-free-paf-sample-data/

If you want to allow users to graphically find their postcode e.g. by clicking on a map you would need a map which returns a National Grid Reference and then use Codepoint data (https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/data_information/os_products/supporting/codepoint_guidance.htm) which is also (an expensive) paid for service to find the nearest postcode co-ordinate using some data structure e.g. quadtree. This will not work correctly in all cases as post code boundaries are not always convex.

Hope that helps